# Python Functions in an expression - holding off on evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I know in python you can do this:

```
def getFunc():
    def func(x):
        return x+4
    return func

f = getFunc()
#8
print(f(4))
```

The part below results in an error. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with different syntax/notation?

```
f1 = getFunc()
f2 = getFunc()

# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'
rslt = f1 + f2

# Evaluate expression by passing in '1' to all functions
# Ideally Outputs f1(1) + f2(1) = 10
rslt(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap them in another function, lambda in this case:

For a generic version:

```
reslt = lambda x: sum(map(lambda f: f(x), (f1, f2)))
```

Where (f1, f2, .. fn) is a tuple with the funtions to apply.

Or a simply hardcoded version:

```
reslt = lambda x: f1(x) + f2(x)
```

Comment: Making it one step harder - what if the expression is more complex than f1 + f2? For example, say the user supplies the expression and can set it arbitrarily e.g. to (f1 + f4) / f5? Is there a way to tell python - evaluate the expression by passing in a single parameter (e.g. '1') to all the functions in the expression.

Comment: you would have to somehow composite the functions. This sounds like that maybe you would need a tree and evaluate the functions for each leaf and then reversed it evaluating the operations.